# High power consumption during power down mode

Tags: power, arduino-pro-mini, sleep

I try to use power down mode to extend battery life, but no matter what sleep library I use, the power consumption never goes below 3.4-3.6 mA. I'm using a chinese pro mini board with VCC input (but using the RAW results the same).

avr/power sketch:

```
#include <avr/power.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h>

void setup()
{          
  Serial.begin(9600);      
  byte i;

  // Ensure no floating pins
  for(i=0; i<20 ; i++)
  {
    pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(i, LOW);
  }

  // Power-down board
  set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);

  sleep_enable();

  // Disable ADC
  ADCSRA &= ~(1 << ADEN);

  // Power down functions
  PRR = 0xFF;

  // Enter sleep mode
  sleep_mode();
}

void loop()
{
}
```

rocketscream/Low-Power sketch:

```
#include <LowPower.h>
void setup() {
}

void loop() {
  LowPower.powerDown(SLEEP_8S, ADC_OFF, BOD_OFF);
}
```

Comment: How are you powering it?

Comment: Using a 5V YwRobot breadboard power supply with VCC pin or a 9V battery with the RAW pin. Both are the same.

Comment: Are you measuring the current before or after the breadboard power supply?

Comment: After. Meanwhile I realized that the power led is always on even when the board is sleeping so I guess thats causing the power usage. I'll try to remove it and test again.

Comment: There is also a voltage regulator on that board, that has some quiescent current.

Comment: All I/O pins must be outputs and not driving a load OR inputs and terminated to high or low.

Comment: See [Power saving techniques for microprocessors](http://www.gammon.com.au/power). The first things I would get rid of are the LED and the voltage regulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried your first sketch on my "bare-bones" board.

[image: Bare-bones board]

With the sketch exactly as written, it used 197 µA.

I wondered why it was that high, so I commented out this line:

```
  Serial.begin(9600);
```

That reduced consumption to 122 nA.

See [Power saving techniques for microprocessors](http://www.gammon.com.au/power).

You need to get rid of any "power" LEDs, and disconnect any voltage regulators. If you want really low consumption you need to have minimal hardware.

Of course, if you *need* the voltage regulator, well so be it. But don't expect 100 nA consumption if you use it.